# Do imperative sentences have intransitive verbs?

Tags: verbs, imperative-sentences

Please guide me if the verbs in these sentences are transitive or intransitive:

> 1. Please do me a favor.
> 2. Close the door!
> 3. Write this note.
> 4. I enjoy walking in the park.

I think these all are transitive. But someone told me that imparative sentences have intransitive verbs.

Comment: There is no such rule. Brief commands such as _Stop! Speak!_ are intransitive verbs, but most longer imperatives include a verb with an object, as in your examples. (_I enjoy walking in the park_ is not an imperative!)

Comment: Imperative is a verb mood; it can be present with either transitive ("Clean your room!") or intransitive ("Sit!") verbs.